# Created jQuery element doesn't parse tags in `text` parameter

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating few elements with jQuery like this -

```
var div1 = $('<div />', {text: "Specials of <b>the searched text</b>"}).attr({"class": "spcl-thmb-hdr"});
div1.appendTo(li2); // appending to a <li /> tag
```

But when they load, they just don't parse the `<b />` tag. and prints something like this -

```
<div class="spcl-thmb-hdr">Specials of &lt;b&gt;the searched text&lt;/b&gt;</div>
```

How do I make it parse the tag in `text` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `html` instead of `text` for the string to be seen as HTML, otherwise it will be encoded.

The map that you pass into `$` can contain attributes, to you can replace the `attr` call, also, like this:

```
$('<div />', {
    html: "Specials of <b>the searched text</b>",
    "class": "spcl-thmb-hdr"
});
```

From [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to `jQuery()` can accept a map consisting of a superset of the properties that can be passed to the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method. Furthermore, any [event type](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val), [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css), [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html), [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text), [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data), [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width), [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height), or [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset). The name `"class"` must be quoted in the map since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and `"className"` cannot be used since it is not the correct attribute name.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of something like that but couldn't find any reference at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). Should have tried before asking. :)

Comment: It's a little hidden in the documentation, what all can go in that second parameter.  I'll add it to my answer.